# How to stop scrolling to top after an ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, scrolltop

I update a certain content of htm element with setInterval function to call an ajax every few sec

```
<div class="content">
<p>New informaton here</p>
<br>
<p>.......</p>
more information below
</div>
```

below is the javascript

```
var main = function(){
        updatingMessage = setInterval(function(){
         $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:" call_MYSQLDatabase_To_Update_Content.php",
        cache:0,
        data:({
           some vars
             }),
        success:function(result){
         $(".content").html(result);
                          }
                 });  
                       }, 1000);
     updatingMessage();
        }
$(document).ready(main);
```

What's bother me is everytime when I scroll down to see the information 
it will scroll to the top of itself after each ajax call. 
Is there anyway to stay at the same `<p>`'s position after an ajax call ?

Comment: You want to stay in the same place you were when ajax was called? What do you want to happen if the new content is shorter than the old content?

Comment: That's exact;y what I meant, I can never reach the information at the bottom if it scrolls to top every second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you must get the element's scroll position, then make sure you maintain that position by setting the scrollTop attribute to the original position.

```
var position = element.scrollTop;

//do some work here, which might change the position

element.scrollTop = position;
```

Comment: So what you mean is like I should get the current <p>'s position where I stop, then scroll to it after ajax call ?

Comment: Yeah this should work. Get the position right when you receive the data, and set it to the same after you have inserted the data into the page. You can add a check to see if new content is shorter, in which case set position to the bottom by using _element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight_

Comment: I assume your `<div>` is scrolling through your `<p>` elements, in which case, get the scroll position of the `<div>` - otherwise, get the scroll position of which ever element is being scrolled and set that to whatever value it was before the ajax call.

Comment: scrolling back to the last position produces a jerk which is not user friendly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have a table with `overflow-y: auto` and a fixed `height: 350px`. The `.scrollTop()` function does not work. Indeed, I tried to read the Y position of `<table>` or `<tbody>`, but it always returns `0`!

When I refresh my `<table>`, the browser reset scroll position on my tables ! I absolutely need to prevent this.

Here is my workaround :

- **update only the contents of `<tbody>` instead of the entire `<table>`**

It works fine, the scroll position of my tables is not reset.

Below is a part of my code that updates 3 tables every 10 seconds:

```js
function updateTables() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/get-tables.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'get',
        data: {
            tableId: [
                'table-actual',
                'table-new',
                'table-history'
            ]
        },
        success: function(response){
            jQuery.each(response, function (key, table) {
                jQuery('#table-' + table.id + ' tbody').html(data.content);
            });
        }
    }); 
}

setInterval(updateTables, 10000);
```

Hope it helps some of you.